# getting count within a findOne of a mongoose schema array field

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to use Mongoose to return information about a user to populate their profile. I've been using findOne to populate a list of their comments along with basic profile information through embedded documents and with .populate. I want to get a count of the friends that they have by counting how many objects are in the friends array.

It looks like aggregate is one of doing that, but how can I use both? or is there a simple way of doing a count in the findOne query?

```html
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username:  String,
  comments       : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
  friends: [
     { 
      id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      permission: Number 
     }
  ]
})
  
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);

app.get('/profile/:username', function(req, res) {
User
.findOne({ username: req.params.username }, 'username friends -_id')
 .populate({
  path: 'current',
  model: 'Comment',
  select: 'comment author -_id date',
  populate: {
   path: 'author',
   model: 'User',
   select: 'username firstName lastName -_id'
  }
 }) 
.exec(function(err, user) {
//
})
)}
```

Comment: Why not using user.friends.length ?

Answer (score 0):

If user returns with friends array, why don't you return just user.friends.length ?

If you want just count, use this

```
User.aggregate([
     {
        $match: { username: req.params.username }
     },
     {
        $unwind: "$comments"
     },
     {
        $lookup: {
           from: "Comment",
           localField: "comments",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "comments"
        }
     },
     { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "friends": { "$first": "$friends"},
            "comments": { "$push": "$comments" }
         }
     },
     {
        $project: {
            _id: 0, 
            count: {$size: '$friends'},
            comments: 1,
            username: 1
        }
     }
]).exec() ...
```

Comment: because I'd be returning a huge array if they have a lot of entires when I just need the count. what if I'm alreadu using findOne with .populate for embedded documents? can I use aggregate to do the same? or can I combine them?

Comment: Well, you cannot use populate method with aggregation. Instead, you have to use lookup method to fetch the comments object. I updated my answer. Search lookup, unwind and group on documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/  .

Comment: Also, I took a look your edited answer. It seems you might not need aggregate. As long as you do not populate friends collection, it will just return the array of object Id list which is ok. You can return that length. If you still do not wanna return object id list, you have to use aggregate which it may take more time to build since I am able to test your collections neither view or all schemas.